# AJAX $.ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my `$.ajax` function. `volunteerDist` is an array in a previous function and it calls `myAjax(volunteerDis);`However, the program always calls the `error` and `complete` functions, with an error message of `undefined`. What should I do? Thanks

`admin-view-available-volunteeers.php` is the filename where this is located
`volunteerDist` is an array that contains floats

```
function myAjax(volunteerDist){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'admin-view-available-volunteeers.php',
            data : ({
                    distance:volunteerDist
                    }),
            success: function(){
                 alert('worked');
                },
           error :function(err){ 
                    alert('nope :( ERROR: ' + err.ErrorMessage);
                },
           complete : function(){
                       alert('thanks');
           }
        });
}
```

Comment: What is the error you see in `firebug`. by the way this is no property  `ErrorMessage`... so you get `undefined`

Comment: What is the response you're getting from the server?

Comment: my system alerts "nope :( ERROR: undefined", which is based on the error function

Comment: @gdoron okay so what is a good advice on how to fix this?

Comment: This is the definition of the function error calls : `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` .... "errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error.""

Comment: @ManseUK where will I place this "error(jqXHR,..)"

Comment: @ManseUK it says Not Found.. what does that mean?

Comment: @BrandonYoung that means `admin-view-available-volunteers.php` isnt found ... check the path !

Comment: but admin-view-available-volunteers.php is the file name of this file

Comment: @BrandonYoung include your whole file - or use http://codepad.org/

Comment: @ManseUK i tried in a different file and it alert "worked". does that mean that the new file already has the whole array?

Comment: @BrandonYoung your filename has a spelling mistake : `admin-view-available-volunteeers.php` has 3 `e`s in volunteer ... is this the problem ?

Comment: ow.. yeah.. but already tried it in a separate php file with a url toDistance.php with the code if(isset($_POST['distance'])){
  $distance = $_POST['distance'];
  $volunteerid = $_POST['id'];
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get better debugging on error you need to update your code, this

```
error :function(err){ 
    alert('nope :( ERROR: ' + err.ErrorMessage);
},
```

will not work - as `err` is a `jqXHR` object!

change it to this :

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert("Error : " + errorThrown);
}
```

This will output the message sent by the server.

All the details for the params of `.ajax()` are [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

### Update

Check the name of your PHP file ...

```
admin-view-available-volunteeers.php
```

has 3 `e`s in the word `volunteer` ... is this the problem ?

Comment: should the url not be the url of the same file?

Comment: @BrandonYoung it can be the same file thats not a problem - but the error "Not Found" means it cant find it - get something like Firebug to ensure the correct file is being called.

Comment: @BrandonYoung your filename has a spelling mistake : `admin-view-available-volunteeers.php` has 3 `e`s in `volunteer` ... is this the problem ?

Comment: yeah.. mistake.. now it tried it in a different filename and it alerted worked already.. is this correct way to get the data?

if(isset($_GET['distance'])){
  $distance = $_GET['distance'];
  $volunteerid = $_GET['id'];
    }

Comment: @BrandonYoung so its working now ? ie its calling your script ?

Comment: yeah.. it does alert worked.. but i cannot get it from the other file

Comment: i had a question, is it automatic that after the $.ajax, it will call or go to the url specified in the function? i am wondering maybe this url is not being called

Answer (score 3):

If your `error:` handler is being called, then *the remote script returned an error*.

Fix the script, not the JS code!

Comment: In this case you're right, but not always. like when you write `dataType :'json'` and the server doesn't return `json`. Anyway +1 for being right here...

Answer (score 1):

I always get this a lot. In your `admin-view-available-volunteers.php` you need to make sure that you're outputting the right headers.

To do that you need to put this in your php before anything is output:

```
header("HTTP/1.01 200 OK");
header("Content-type: text/html");
```

Otherwise it is returned as a 404 to jQuery's ajax and then goes into the error and complete bits.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try loading a different test file first, something simple that way you can test the js separately and ensure that when you hit the php script directly in your browser that there are no errors shown.

Also in the future make sure you have all these ajax calls on the same domain as your php scripts(like you do now), otherwise ajax won't work across domains without adding a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" header.